# Need help investigating Azure App Service .NET Core 2.1 ArgumentOutOfRangeException and System.OverflowException

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.1

Today I've adjusted the **App Service Log** settings for my Azure App Serivce: a .NET Core 2.1 Web API. Soon after I changed the **Application Logging (file system)** setting from Information to Warning, my application stopped responding. I immediately kicked of a .NET Trace using the **Diagnose and solve problems** feature.

This Trace report showed the following:

```
system.private.corelib!
microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting!
System.Private.CoreLib!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start
microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.il!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Views.ErrorPage.ExecuteAsync
microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting!
System.Private.CoreLib!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start
microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.il!Microsoft.Extensions.RazorViews.BaseView.ExecuteAsync
microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting!
microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting!
System.Private.CoreLib!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1+<>c[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol+<ProcessRequests>d__188`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingApplication+Context]].<.cctor>b__9_0
system.private.corelib!
System.Private.CoreLib!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol+<ProcessRequests>d__188`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingApplication+Context]].MoveNext
system.private.corelib!
system.private.corelib!
system.private.corelib!
system.private.corelib!
system.private.corelib!
```

Same time, the Azure Blob log showed these lines:

```
2019-07-06 14:04:06.476 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Connection id "0HLO233NHLK6Q", Request id "0HLO233NHLK6Q:000003BF": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(String value)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.RazorViews.BaseView.Write(String value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Views.ErrorPage.ExecuteAsync()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.RazorViews.BaseView.ExecuteAsync(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)

2019-07-06 14:04:19.245 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Connection id "0HLO233NHLK6T", Request id "0HLO233NHLK6T:000000EF": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and count must refer to a location within the buffer.
Parameter name: chars
   at System.Text.EncoderNLS.GetBytes(Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex, Int32 charCount, Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Boolean flush)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(String value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Views.ErrorPage.ExecuteAsync()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.RazorViews.BaseView.ExecuteAsync(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

These stacktraces don't show any of my own code, they seem framework related.

Is there a message or a hint in these error stack traces that I can use to prevent these situations?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late but maybe my answer will help someone else.
I received the same exceptions as you. But it was not Azure App Service but IIS. The problem was in incorrect configuration somewhere in Startup.cs. You webhost tried to show error page but at the same time App Service (or IIS in my case) tried to shut down or restart it.

This thread helped me a lot https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1737